# Convolution of two identically distributed uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Problem:** If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, both uniformly distributed on $(0, 1)$, calculate the probability density of $X + Y$.

**Solution**: Since we have

$$f_{X}(a) = f_{Y}(a) = \begin{cases}
1 & 0 < a < 1 \\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

we obtain

$$f_{X + Y}(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}(a - y)f_{Y}(y) \mathop{dy} = \int_{0}^{1} f_{X}(a - y) \mathop{dy}.$$

For $0 \leq a \leq 1$, this yields $f_{X + Y}(a) = \int_{0}^{a} \mathop{dy} = a$

For $1 < a < 2$, we get $f_{X + Y}(a) = \int_{a - 1}^{1} \mathop{dy} = 2 - a$.

For any other value of $a$, we obtain the integral equal to $0$.

**My question:** I understand how they got $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_{X}(a - y)f_{Y}(y) \mathop{dy}$ for the convolution of $X$ and $Y$ because $F_{X + Y}(a) = \Pr\{X + Y \leq a\} = \int \int f_{X}(x) f_{Y}(y) \mathop{dx} \mathop{dy}$ over the region $x + y \leq a$.

I'm not sure why $f_{X + Y}(a) = \int_{0}^{1} f_{X}(a - y) \mathop{dy}$. Is that because $f_{Y}(a) = 1$ on the interval from $0$ to $1$? But what about when $1 < a < 2$? Wouldn't the integral just become $0$ in this case then?

Next, I'm not sure why the bounds are $0$ and $a$ for $0 \leq a \leq 1$ or why the bounds are $a-1$ to $1$ for the second integral.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure why $f_{X + Y}(a) = \int_{0}^{1} f_{X}(a - y) \mathop{dy}$. Is that because $f_{Y}(a) = 1$ on the interval from $0$ to $1$? But what about when $1 < a < 2$? Wouldn't the integral just become $0$ in this case then?

No, it is because $f_Y(y)=1$ when $y\in(0;1)$ else $f_Y(y)=0$, and because $y$ is the bound variable of integration.$$\begin{align}f_{X+Y}(a)&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(a-y,y)~\mathsf d y\\[1ex] &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X+Y}(a-y)~f_Y(y)~\mathsf dy \\[1ex] &= \int_0^1 f_{X+Y}(a-y)~\mathsf dy\end{align}$$

Now $f_X(a-y)=1$ when $0\lt a-y\lt 1$ else $f_X(a-y)=0$ and we know $(0;2)$ is the support for $f_{X+Y}$

$$\begin{align}f_{X+Y}(a)  &= \int_0^1~\mathbf 1_{0\lt a\lt 2~,~ a-1\lt y\lt a}~\mathsf dy\\[1ex]  &= \mathbf 1_{0\lt a\lt 2}\int_{\max(0,a-1)}^{\min(1,a)}~\mathsf dy \\[2ex] &=\mathbf 1_{0\lt a\lt 1}\int_0^a~\mathsf d y+\mathbf 1_{1\leq a\lt 2}\int_{a-1}^1~\mathsf d y\end{align}$$

---

Okay, we have the supports, $0<y<1$ for $f_Y(y)$ and $a-1<y<a$ for $f_X(a-y)$, then since the support of $y$ for their product is the intersection of both, and it is thusly $\max(0,a-1)< y< \min(1,a)$ . This is relative to $a$, which itself is supported over $0<a<2$.

Those min/max functions are a little annoying, so we shall partition the support for $f_{X+Y}(a)$ into $0<a<1$ union $1\leqslant a< 1$.   Thusly in the first part, the bounds for the integraton are $0$ to $a$ while for the second part they are $a-1$ to $1$.

---

PS: The notation is an indicator function, having value of 1 when the indice is true, and 0 otherwise. $$\mathbf 1_{E}=\begin{cases}1&:& E\\0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $f_{X}(a - y) = 1$ when $0 < a - y < 1$? (exclusive inequalities).

Comment: I still don't understand why for $0 \leq a \leq 1$ we get $f_{X + Y}(a) = \int_{0}^{a} \mathop{dy}. $ I'm not familiar with the bolded $1$ notation you are using